# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined after querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a javascript and getting some error. I am using jquery repeater to catch some repeatable products.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#discount', function(){
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
   var loopNo = document.querySelectorAll('.count_list .list_repeat').length;
   var i;
   var sum = 0;
   for(i=0;i<=loopNo;i++){
       var selling_price = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("sell_products[".concat(i).concat("][selling_price]"))[0].value);

       var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("sell_products[".concat(i).concat
    ("][quantity]"))[0].value);

       var selling_price_quantity = selling_price * quantity;

       sum = sum + (selling_price_quantity - parseInt(document.getElementsByName("sell_products[".concat(i).concat("][discount]"))[0].value));

}
   document.getElementById('total_amount').innerHTML = sum;    });
```

This is the code for what I want to get but I am getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined** this error. I am not able to solve it. Here you can get the full codes. https://pastebin.com/tzwu0tsq . Can anyone please help?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you dumped/logged the objet that is says is undefined?  And what does this have to do with PHP? Please remove the PHP and Laravel5 tags if this is really just a javascript issue.

Comment: Patrick no problem with PHP. its just a javascript issue. I already removed the PHP and laravel tag.

Comment: `concat("][selling_price]")` It looks like you're trying to use the `selling_price` variable in the same line where you define it. Unless you have it defined globally somewhere, it's not going to exist the first time through the loop.

Comment: Looking your code quickly, I think 'parseInt' will not give what you want from the array object that you bringing with 'getElementsByName'. And doesn´t matter if exists only one object with the name you´re passing.

Comment: Maybe you should use 'parseFloat' insted 'parseInt' to treat prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem. I am getting this error because of wrong info in for loop.

```
for(i=0;i<loopNo;i++)
```

This start from 0 but only 1 div get from  querySelectorAll. so the loop have to be continue less then 1.